# I have the following webpage designed in html now i want to change it to fit for all mobiles and ipad

Tags: iphone, twitter-bootstrap, ipad, zend-framework

```
### my header where i include bootstrap ###


 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <title>RestaurantBash</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <!-- Bootstrap -->
            <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
            <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
            <link href="/css/template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
            <script src="/js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/js/jquery.formatCurrency-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        </head>
        <body>
            <div  class="container" style="position:absolute;">
                <div style="min-height:100%; width:100%; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                    <?php echo $this->layout()->content ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>


### my phtml file loads into container ###
```

How it works
    It's easy to find delicious deals and save 
      money
 at top restaurants in your area!

Sign Up Now!

Already a member? [Log-in](/user/login)

Comment: You have to use the Bootstrap classes, you should not have to use the `style` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As far your code I think you are using RWD Bootstrap framework. Bootsrap frame work will automatically adjust pages in all type of device. You can learn [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/).

For more you can check my [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211090/how-to-auto-adjust-the-div-size-for-all-mobile-tablet-display-formats/25380422#25380422)