# Responsive on page load popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magento

Currently I have this and it works perfect for mobile but the size is way too small for desktop.

```
<!-- Main Stylesheet -->
<p><link href="/adpopup-pro.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" /></p>

<!-- jQuery (load only if needed) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Main Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/adpopup-pro.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[

$(document).ready(function() {

    var ads = {
      'ad_1': {
        'type': 'image',
        'src': 'imagelink',
        'link': 'link',
      }

    }

    $('body').adPopupPro({
      ads: ads,
      width:320,
      height:320,
      overlay_color:'dark',
    });
  });
// ]]></script>
```

Is there anyway to somehow enclose this and have it load only on mobile and load another on desktop and larger sizes?

Comment: Check the size of the screen before executing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715124/do-something-if-screen-width-is-less-than-960-px

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {

}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {

}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {

}
```

EDIT: here is a link with a similar answer
[How to auto adjust the div size for all mobile / tablet display formats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211090/how-to-auto-adjust-the-div-size-for-all-mobile-tablet-display-formats)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to check by your user-agent resolution and retrieve different values for your ad width and height.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var ads = {
      'ad_1': {
        'type': 'image',
        'src': 'imagelink',
        'link': 'link',
      }

    }

    $('body').adPopupPro({
      ads: ads,
      width:(function(){ 
        if(window.innerWidth>768){ //could be any breakpoint value! 
           var width = 320;
        }
        else{
           var width = 200;
        }
        return width; 
      })(),
      height: (function(){ 
        if(window.innerWidth<768){ //could be any breakpoint value! 
           var height = 320;
        }
        else{
           var height = 200;
        }
        return width; 
      })(),
      overlay_color:'dark',
    });
});
// ]]>
```

Comment: Seemed like a good solution. Doesn't load the popup

Comment: Any thoughts on making this work? Seems like it should

Comment: Basically at this point I think I need to load two different codes. One for mobile, one for desktop. How can this be achieved?